# lateIntailizatationError and Nullcheckoperator

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

when I compiled my app the error{LateInitializationError: Field 'contorller' has not been initialized} appeared and when I changed the Late keyword with ? operator and Put ! before the methods that depends on the variable like stackoverflow suggests another error appeared {Null check operator used on a null value} so how can I solved that

itis a statful class

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
BarcodeDetector ?labeler;
CameraController? controller;
bool isBusy = false;
String result = "";
File ?_image;
ImagePicker ?imagePicker;
CameraImage ?img;
void initState() {
super.initState();
labeler = FirebaseVision.instance.barcodeDetector();
  }
intializeCamera() async {
controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
await controller!.initialize().then((_) {
if (!mounted) {
return;
}
controller!.startImageStream((image) => {
if (!isBusy) {isBusy = true, img = image, doBarcodeScanning()}
});
});
  }



void dispose() {
controller!.dispose();
labeler!.close();
super.dispose();
  }



Center(
child: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
height: 220,
width: 220,
child: AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: controller!.value.aspectRatio,
child: CameraPreview(controller),
),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`intializeCamera()` is a future method, I will encourage you to use `FutureBuilder` in this case. It takes some time to initialize data being future.

Second case is `controller` is nullable, means it can receive null data, which is good to have.
`CameraController? controller;`

But while using a null check on it, then handle the situation.

You can also just handle like this

```dart
  if (controller != null)
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                      height: 220,
                      width: 220,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: CameraPreview(controller),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your controllers in `initState()` before using them in `build()` and don't define controllers as `null` - rather use the `late` keyword.